# Updating MySQL Table With Random Sorting

Tags: mysql, database, random

I have one table like so

```
ItemsTable

item_id, cat_id, sort
----------------------
1        1       1
20       1       2
15       1       3
12       1       4
11       1       5
....
1521     1       1991
```

In my program, every time a page is shown, it will pull the next item based on the sort number. So, say I just showed sort = 2, the next time the page will show item sort = 3 (maybe sort is a bad name).

What I want to do is that once I pull the last item (sort = 1991), I want to re-update the items in that table and re-assign new sort order.

Like this:

```
ItemsTable

item_id, cat_id, sort
----------------------
35       1       1
7        1       2
2        1       3
1521     1       4
700      1       5
....
5        1       1991
```

Right now my mind is thinking I have to write a script that SELECTS records where cat_id = 1 sorts the results randomly, then i'd have to create a loop in PHP that would update the database 1001 times. This doesn't seem efficient in my mind.

Can you guys provide a better alternative? What is the most efficient way to do this with MySQL?

Comment: You can't automate the reordering based on when data is selected.  You can write code to do the reordering, but your app will need to fire that code at the appropriate time.

Comment: Correct. I have all of that set up. What I'm having problems with is the query that fires up that randomly re-assigns sort order, but keeps it sequential for that category.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @row := 0;
UPDATE ItemsTable SET sort = (@row := @row + 1) WHERE cat_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND();
```

Ok after some hours of research and trying things out this solved my issue.
It now generates a sequence of numbers that are random.

I know that RAND() is not very efficient, but that is another problem for another day :)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution to me.  You'll just want to make sure this UPDATE is run offline or in some other way that it won't block page loads while it's running.  Otherwise every n pageloads will be unusually slow.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
order by cat_id, rand()
```

Or, are you trying to get the result set twice:

```
select item_id, cat_id, sort
from ((select t.*, 0 as whichgroup
       from t
      )
      union all
      (select t.*, 1 as whichgroup
       from t
      )
     ) t
order by cat_id, whichgroup,
         (case when whichgroup = 0 then sort
               else rand()
          end)
```

This outputs each record twice, first in the "sort" order and then randomly.

Based on your comment, this may be what you want:

```
order by cat_id,
         (case when sort <= 1991 then sort else rand() end)
```

Comment: No, I meant that once the 1991th item is shown, that the whole table gets resorted, but the new sort values are kept until the 1991th item is shown again.

Comment: In SQL, tables are unordered.  Query results are ordered.  Could you rephrase your question to clarify what you really need?

Comment: Basically, I want to keep a sort order of the records in the table until a threshold is reach in my program. Once that threshold is reached (in other words, item 1521 is shown). Update the table with a new random sort order that will be static until the next threshold has been reached at which point the database gets re-sorted again.